# Update multiple columns from a sub query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
UPDATE PINPOINT_SUPPLEMENT
            SET (ATTACHMENT_VALUE,ATTACHMENT_TYPE) = (
            SELECT key,'file'
            FROM PINPOINT_DOCUMENT
            WHERE PINPOINT_SUPPLEMENT.ATTACHMENT_VALUE::integer = PINPOINT_DOCUMENT.DOCUMENT_ID
            )
WHERE ATTACHMENT_VALUE IS NULL
```

Getting Error when i execute this query

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 3:             SELECT key,'file

Comment: What is your Postgres version? (`select version();` will tell you)

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.4.23 @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Unrelated, to your problem, but: why do you need the cast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update PINPOINT_SUPPLEMENT
set
    ATTACHMENT_VALUE = PINPOINT_DOCUMENT.key,
    ATTACHMENT_TYPE = 'file'
from PINPOINT_DOCUMENT
where
    PINPOINT_SUPPLEMENT.ATTACHMENT_VALUE::integer = PINPOINT_DOCUMENT.DOCUMENT_ID
    and PINPOINT_SUPPLEMENT.ATTACHMENT_VALUE IS NULL
```

or

```
update PINPOINT_SUPPLEMENT
set
    (ATTACHMENT_VALUE,ATTACHMENT_TYPE) = (PINPOINT_DOCUMENT.key, 'file')
from PINPOINT_DOCUMENT
where
    PINPOINT_SUPPLEMENT.ATTACHMENT_VALUE::integer = PINPOINT_DOCUMENT.DOCUMENT_ID
    and PINPOINT_SUPPLEMENT.ATTACHMENT_VALUE IS NULL
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Support for updating tuples was introduced in Postgres 9.5, so you can't use that syntax with your version.

But as the second value is a constant I don't see a reason to use that syntax to begin with:

```
UPDATE PINPOINT_SUPPLEMENT
  SET ATTACHMENT_VALUE = (SELECT "key"
                          FROM PINPOINT_DOCUMENT
                          WHERE PINPOINT_SUPPLEMENT.ATTACHMENT_VALUE::integer = PINPOINT_DOCUMENT.DOCUMENT_ID), 
       ATTACHMENT_TYPE = 'file'
WHERE ATTACHMENT_VALUE IS NULL
```

Note, that the sub-query might result in an error if there is more than one `ATTACHMENT_VALUE` for a `document_id`!

Comment: Does this update query supports for Oracle as well ?